# Data Analysis with python using numpy. Plot graph with Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Using `matplotlib` and `numpy`. **`pandas` is not available**.

The file with the data is on the website https://covid.saude.gov.br/, in the upper right corner. If in .xslx, save as UTF-8 CSV. If possible easier to use the numpy, matplotlib modules.

- The number of deaths in a specific state and one day of the month. It must be possible to choose another day and another state and repeat the process until there is a request to leave the program.
- Show difference between one day and another.
- Save in a new file the information of the two previous items (status and percentage)
- Create two charts with the information. month x difference and month x number of deaths.
  I thought of something like that but it's not going. I transformed the file to .txt.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

# 1: Opening the file and saving the data in the matrix (OK?)

arq=open('arq_COVID.csv','r',encoding='UTF-8')
C=arq.readline()
matriz=[]
for line in arq:
    matriz.append(line[:-1].split(';'))
arq.close

#2: Numpy array storage (not OK?)

print('Linhas: ',len(matriz),'\nColunas: ',len(matriz[0]))
matrizn=np.zeros((len(matriz),len(matriz[0])),dtype=object)
for i in range(matrizn.shape[0]): 
    for j in range(matrizn.shape[1]): 
        if j==7:
            matrizn[i,j]=datetime.strptime(matriz[i][j],'%d/%m/%Y').date() 
        elif j==0 or j==1 or j==2 or j==6:
            matrizn[i,j]=matriz[i][j]
        else:
            matrizn[i,j]=float(matriz[i][j]) # -> ValueError: could not convert string to float:''
                                             #Probably have some empty value (''). How to solve?
                                             
# 3: Search for elements (No have idea...HELP!). 
continue = 'Y'
while (continue == 'Y'):
    md=[];me=[];tdeath=[]
    print('='*30)
    day=input('Choose a day of the month: ')
    for x in range(len(matrizn)):
        if x==day:
           md=matrizn.append([x,7])         
    print('='*30)
    state=input('Choose a state: ')
    for y in range(len(matrizn)):
        if y==state:
            ms=matrizn.append([y,1])
    for w in range(len(matrizn)):
        if w==tdeath:
            tdeath=matrizn.append([w,12])
    else:
        print('='*30)
        continuar = input('Do you wish to continue [Y/N]? ')
 
# 4:Subtraction of elements (No have idea... HELP! )

matrizn1=np.zeros((len(md),len(tdeaths[0])),dtype=object)   
for i in range(matrizn1.shape[0]):                            
    for j in range(matrizn1.shape[1]):
        if j==0:
            matrizn1[i,j]=matrizn[i][12]-tdeaths
    
        else:
            matrizn1[i,j]=0  

# 5: Write the data to another file (OK?)

arq1=open('Covid.csv','w')
for i in range(matrizn1.shape[0]):
    line=''
    for j in range(matrizn1.shape[1]):
        line=line+str(matrizn1[i,j])+'\t'
    line=line[:-1]+'n'
    arq1.write(linha) 
arq1.close

# 6: Plot graphs (OK?)

plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(matrizn[:,7],matrizn[:,12],'-b',label='Number of deaths')
plt.title('Evolution COVID-19')
plt.ylabel('Month')
plt.xlabel('Number of deaths')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('cov1.png')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(matrizn1[:,0],matrizn1[:,1],'-r',label='Percentage')
plt.title('Percentage')
plt.ylabel('Month')
plt.xlabel('Percentage')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('cov2.png')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show
```

Comment: Thank´s Trenton.